# ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword

Tags: oracle11g, dbvisualizer

I have moved the VALUES clause to different locations in the statement but no luck. I am a Novice and any assistance is appreciated. Thank you.

```
INSERT INTO KEYITEM.296 (KEYVALUECHAR, KEYSETNUM)
VALUES ('NOT PUBLIC', 0)
SELECT
    KEYITEM296.KEYVALUECHAR,
    KEYITEM296.KEYSETNUM
FROM
    ITEMDATA
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    KEYITEM296
ON
    (
       ITEMDATA.ITEMNUM = KEYITEM296.ITEMNUM)
WHERE
    ITEMDATA.ITEMTYPENUM = 862 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm DB2 fan, but you cannot mix VALUES and SELECT in INSERT.

The correct SQL would be for INSERTing data:

```
INSERT INTO KEYITEM.296 (KEYVALUECHAR, KEYSETNUM)
SELECT
    KEYITEM296.KEYVALUECHAR,
    KEYITEM296.KEYSETNUM
FROM
    ITEMDATA
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    KEYITEM296
ON
    (
       ITEMDATA.ITEMNUM = KEYITEM296.ITEMNUM)
WHERE
    ITEMDATA.ITEMTYPENUM = 862
```

or

```
INSERT INTO KEYITEM.296 (KEYVALUECHAR, KEYSETNUM)
VALUES ('NOT PUBLIC', 0)
```

Or if you want to do INSERT and then SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO KEYITEM.296 (KEYVALUECHAR, KEYSETNUM)
VALUES ('NOT PUBLIC', 0);
SELECT
    KEYITEM296.KEYVALUECHAR,
    KEYITEM296.KEYSETNUM
FROM
    ITEMDATA
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    KEYITEM296
ON
    (
       ITEMDATA.ITEMNUM = KEYITEM296.ITEMNUM)
WHERE
    ITEMDATA.ITEMTYPENUM = 862 ;
```

Comment: Kovica Tim execute two queries , on insert into

Comment: and on left join, in the first query he insert datas, and in the second execute left join, but when he executes left join , he don't set  ITEMNUM value

Comment: One of the problems is KEYITEM.296 and KEYITEM296. Whichone is correct?

Comment: KEYITEM296 i think because table with name = 296 it's not normal, '.' it's used in order separate schema from table

Comment: INSERT INTO KEYITEM296 (KEYVALUECHAR, KEYSETNUM)
VALUES ('NOT PUBLIC', 0);
Then in the select you want to see this inserted record? How if the ITENNUM is NULL. Is ITEMNUM a generated column?

Comment: But in left join condition he sets "KEYITEM296.ITEMNUM" so KEYITEM296 have this column, so i added in my query

Comment: Right, this means that the comparison for the join is done on the ITENNUM record. Left join means give me all rows from the left table (ITEMDATA) and match them with the right table (KEYITEM296). If the match fails then you get a NULL, otherwise a data from the right table. For more see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15989/discussion-between-kovica-and-candie)

Comment: So, if you don't get the row you inserted in the first SQL, this means that the ITEMNUM is NULL and you have to include it into the INSERT: 
INSERT INTO KEYITEM296 (KEYVALUECHAR, KEYSETNUM, ITEMNUM) 
VALUES ('NOT PUBLIC', 0, 'FOO');

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO KEYITEM296 (KEYVALUECHAR, KEYSETNUM, ITEMNUM)
VALUES ('NOT PUBLIC', 0, 862 );

  --You must complete your insert with ITEMNUM
  -- you must add ; separator
  -- you must delete '.' of your query

SELECT
    KEYITEM296.KEYVALUECHAR,
    KEYITEM296.KEYSETNUM
FROM
    ITEMDATA
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    KEYITEM296
ON
    (
       ITEMDATA.ITEMNUM = KEYITEM296.ITEMNUM)
WHERE
    ITEMDATA.ITEMTYPENUM = 862 ;
```